# Restart test from last failure case

Tags: unit-testing, pytest

Is there an option to tell py.test to restart from the last failure case? This is particularly important as I am running over lot of  possible scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

If you install 'pytest-cache'  you have '--lf'  option to run the last failures.